# Problema con funcion remove JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un problema con el `REMOVE`, actualmente tengo una tabla dinámica con la cual agrego mas filas y también agregue un enlace llamado `REMOVE` el cual debería quitar la fila, pero actualmente no me esta realizando la función de remover, la de insertar la fila si funciona perfectamente.

Mi codigo `JavaScript` es el siguiente:

```
<script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //1. Add new row
            $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $tableBody = $("#objetivos");
                var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
                var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

                var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
                $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" id="removecell">Remove</a>');
                $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
                    // Replaced Name
                    var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
                    var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
                    $(this).attr('name', newN);
                    //Replaced value
                    var type = $(this).attr('type');
                    if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                        $(this).attr('value', '');
                    }

                    // If you have another Type then replace with default value
                    $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

                });
                $trLast.after($trNew);

                // Re-assign Validation
                var form = $("form")
                    .removeData("validator")
                    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            });

            // 2. Remove
            $('#removecell').live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Mi vista es la siguiente:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <br /><br />
    <div><a class="btn btn-info" href="#" id="addNew">+</a></div>
    <br />
        <table id="objetivos" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombres</th>
                <th>Objetivos</th>
                <th>Puntaje</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
            {
                int j = 0;
                foreach (var i in Model)
                {
                    <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].nombres, new { @class = "form-control"})</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].objetivos, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].puntaje, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (j > 0)
                            {
                                <a href="#" class="removecell">Remove</a>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    j++;
                }
            }
        </table>
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save Bulk Data" />
}
```

> Si hay alguna manera de modernizar el código `JavaScript` estoy abierto a todas sus propuestas desde que no pierda la funcionalidad.

Comment: que versión de jquery estas usando??

Comment: 1.10.2, segun vi el live ya es obsoleto y se debe cambiarlo a on() sin embargo sigue sin funcionar, acabo de intentar tambien $(document).on('click', 'a.removecell', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });   sin embargo sigue sin funcionar

Comment: $('.removecell') ?

Comment: $('.removecell').on('click', 'a.removecell', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });  no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El evento `.live()` ya no existe en jQuery 1.10.2, fue eliminado en la versión 1.9

Cambia el evento a esto:

```
$('#objetivos').on("click", '.removecell', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

ya que el elemento es dinámico y este no carga el evento que le pertenece.

Lo que hago es seleccionar la tabla y posteriormente le asigno el evento a todo elemento con la clase `removecell`

```
$('#objetivos').on("click", '.removecell', function (e) {...});
```

después la función `.closest('elementName')` lo que hace es buscar desde el elemento seleccionado, todos los padres hasta llegar al que tenga el nombre que estoy buscando, puede ser una clase, id o nombre de etiqueta.

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: No amigo, efectivamente no me quiere funcionar no remueve

Comment: ya limpiaste la caché? `Ctrl + Mayus + R` o ejecutar en modo incógnito, revisa también la clase del elemento, si el elemento es seleccionado por id solo funcionara con el primero

Comment: si señor, ya intente mediante el modo incognito y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: en el evento $("#addNew").click tienes la siguiente linea: `$trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" id="removecell">Remove</a>');` cambia el "id" por "class" y deberia funcionar, si no puede que tengas que agregar el evento click a ese elemento cada vez que agregues una fila

Comment: si bro arregle esa parte pero sigue igual dando problema, dado a que es un estudio que estoy haciendo acabo de subir el link https://mega.nz/#!NzoWFbZI!qmEr6k2kJ5bH2sxpvx7LrMFEehuJc4l8h7Fdfkqgr5k  por si quieres revisar